# Ipad : How to test performance on all iPad models without owning them all?

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator

While writing an iPad game, I used the simulator to check out the functionality.  After I had the code 90% done, I borrowed a friends iPad to try it on real HW.  I found that my program was not offering the same refresh rate as the simulator.  (The moral of the story is that you always have to test on real HW to be sure.)

I am planning on buying the iPad2, but am concerned that any code I check out on it (with dual cores, etc) will not alleviate my concern regarding performance on the original iPad.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem without buying/borrowing an iPad whenever I need to check some code out?  Are there some setting in the simulator which more closely mimic the original?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no other simulator. Apple recommends testing on all devices.

Find a tester base with your target devices.